# Using hidden [.section] in .conf file - Smarty

Tags: php, mysql, web-config, load, smarty

First of all, please stick to the problem, not to everything else :)

Ok, my problem is that i trying to use the .conf file in SMARTY, where the problem begins. I would like du use the .Hidden part and not only the globals.

data.conf File

```
 # global variables
 pageTitle = "Main Menu"
 bodyBgColor = #000000
 tableBgColor = #000000
 rowBgColor = #00ff00

[Customer]
pageTitle = "Customer Info"

[Login]
pageTitle = "Login"
focus = "username"
Intro = """This is a value that spans more
       than one line. you must enclose
       it in triple quotes."""

# hidden section -> This par is where my problem starts. I can't use this
[.Database]
host=my.example.com
db=ADDRESSBOOK
user=php-user
pass=foobarenter code here
```

In my PHP file i have this code:

```
require_once("configs/smarty/Smarty.class.php");
$smarty = new Smarty;

$smarty->setConfigDir('configs/');
$smarty->setTemplateDir('templates/');
$smarty->setCompileDir('templates_c/');
$smarty->setPluginsDir('plugins/');
$smarty->setCacheDir('cache/');


## DATABASE ##
$database = $smarty->configLoad('data.conf', '.Database');
$db_host = $database->getConfigVars('host');
$db_name = $database->getConfigVars('db');
$db_user = $database->getConfigVars('user');
$db_pass = $database->getConfigVars('pass');

try{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name,   
    $db_user, $db_pass);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

And this give me this output:

```
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Just in case no one will give a proper answer, you could do a workaround like `$db = clone $smarty; 
$db->config_read_hidden = true;
$db->configLoad('data.conf','Database'); /* remove the dot in section name */ ...`

Comment: Thanks @sofl. I'm still building the page, so it's not a hurry yet. After searching around the web for a solution, I found out that i'm not the only one having this problem.

Comment: Nobody have a answar on this?